# Select random records

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've got one table. It's linked (no primary key) called "spcDB". I need to select randomly 12 records depending on "area" and "location" column. The area has two number values : "211" and "231". I need to select 8 - "211" and 4 - "231" records. Every value from "location" is unique.

I wrote this VBA code (moduleOne):

`Function Randomizer() As Integer
    Static AlreadyDone As Integer
        If AlreadyDone = False Then Randomize: AlreadyDone = True
    Randomizer = 0
End Function`

..and my SELECTs looks like..

```
SELECT TOP 8 spcDB.LOC, spcDB.AREA_TYPE
FROM spcDB
WHERE randomizer() = 0 and spcDB.AREA_TYPE = "211"
ORDER BY rnd(isnull(spcDB.LOC) * 0 + 1);

SELECT TOP 4 spcDB.LOC, spcDB.AREA_TYPE
FROM spcDB
WHERE randomizer() = 0 and spcDB.AREA_TYPE = "231"
ORDER BY rnd(isnull(spcDB.LOC) * 0 + 1);
```

First generate 8 pair of locations and 211 areas. Second 4 loc + 231 areas.
My question is how to combine these two selects into one?

Comment: put UNION ALL between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will use the same sequence if you close and reopen Access.
To avoid this, add a time dependent seed to *Rnd* which changes for every unique id:

```
SELECT TOP 8
    spcDB.LOC, 
    spcDB.AREA_TYPE,
    Rnd(-Timer()*spcDB.LOC) AS [Rnd Generator] 
FROM 
    spcDB
WHERE 
    spcDB.AREA_TYPE = "211"
ORDER BY
    Rnd(-Timer()*spcDB.LOC)

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 4
    spcDB.LOC, 
    spcDB.AREA_TYPE,
    Rnd(-Timer()*spcDB.LOC) AS [Rnd Generator] 
FROM 
    spcDB
WHERE 
    spcDB.AREA_TYPE = "231"
ORDER BY
    Rnd(-Timer()*spcDB.LOC)
```